# Multiple Entities In One MS CRM Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I am trying to create a workflow the gets an entities attribute value and minuses it from another entities attribute value and then have a conditional check on the result. The workflow needs to be run from an account and link to the other entity.

Comment: It seems a workflow is linked to 1 entity, in my case Account. But I need information from another entity, to minus it from the balance of the account. I have tried using an action with an input, but that then requires the user to select the other entity.

Comment: How are the two objects linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second entity is related to the account, you can do this with a normal workflow.  In your Update step select the field that you are calculating, and in the "Form Assistant" window on the right side of the screen select Operator = "Decrement by" and then select the related entity and field that hold the value you wish to subtract.

If the second entity is not related to the account then you have no easy options.

Comment: I did figure it out and came here to see you've  answered. Thank you forfor you help.